# Programa que no encuentra una función aún definida

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de modelar el estado en el que estaríamos y los movimientos que podemos hacer en un árbol binario como el siguiente:

```
           10
         /    \
        6      14
       / \    /  \
      5   8  11  18
```

Utiliso el codigo dado por Alex Allain [aqui](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html). En un momento intento usar una función que me da la cantidad de nudos a los que puedo ir : `int Board::legalMoves(Move moves)` :

```
// gives the number of leaves we can play : either 2 or 0 in the binary-tree case.
int Board::legalMoves(Move moves){
    //If there is leaves there is at least two moves.
n emarg if(n.left != NULL){// wrong we have to take move into account
        return 2;   
    }//otherwise there is no possibilities
    else{
        return 0;
    }

};

double playout (Board * board) {
    Move moves [2];
    //Move moves [MaxLegalMoves];
    while (true) {
        int nb = board->legalMoves (moves);
        if ((nb == 0) || board->terminal ())
            return board->score ();
            int n = rand () % nb;
            board->play (moves [n]);
        if (board->length >= MaxPlayoutLength - 20) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

`Move` es una estructura que contiene un vector de nodos a la que puedo ir desde el nodo `n`. Por ejemplo, desde `14` podemos ir en `11` y `18`. Pero desde `11` no hay nada.

Sin embargo me contesto el compilador que no hay esta funcion :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘double playout(Board*)’:
main.cpp:197:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘Board::legalMoves(Move [2])’
   int nb = board->legalMoves (moves);
```

Sin embargo, ha sido declarado, ¿no?

El código completo está en el [siguiente repositorio de GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/NestedMonteCarloForBinaryTrees). Es, por desgracia, aún no funcional.

Comment: Es curioso que te de error ahí y no en, por ejemplo, `board->play (moves [n]);`. ¿ Error tipográfico ?

Comment: Hola @Trauma ! No entiendo bien, ¿Qué error debería haber obtenido?

Comment: La llamas de 2 formas distintas: `board->play( moves[n] )` y `board->play( moves )`. ¿ Error tipográfico ?

Answer (score 1):

legalMoves()  requiere un valor del tipo Move, pero en esta llamada a funcion envias una direccion de memoria (un valor del tipo Move *).

int nb = board->legalMoves (moves);

Recuerda que el nombre de un array en realidad es un puntero (un puntero constante o que siempre apunta al mismo sitio) que apunta al primer elemento de una serie de elementos.

Para acceder a sus los elementos de un array tenenemos que desreferenciarlos o bien con el operador * (#1) o bien accediendo a los elementos con notacion de arrays (#2)

int nb = board->legalMoves ( *(moves + 1) );  // 1
int nb = board->legalMoves (moves[0]);          // 2

Con eso deberia bastar, aun asi, te voy a describir el mensaje de error.

Primero, el identificador moves no es solo un puntero al primer elemento del array; moves es un puntero al array completo.

Esto puede comprobarse aplicando sizeof con moves. Si aplicas sizeof con el nombre de un array obtienes la suma en bytes de todos sus elementos, en este caso, el tamaño de une Move multiplicado por los dos elementos que tiene el array.

Y por eso el mensaje de error es este:
 error: no matching function for call to ‘Board::legalMoves(Move [2])’
   int nb = board->legalMoves (moves);

Realmente te esta diciendo que encuentra ninguna version de legalMoves() que acepte un valor Moves *, como por ejemplo, echa un vistazo a estos prototipos:
int legalMoves(Move ar[2]);
int legalMoves(Move ar[]);
int legalMoves(Move * ar);

Los tres prototipos son equivalentes en cuanto a funcionalidad, ya que todos aceptan un valor Move*. La unica diferencia es que conceptualmente los dos primeros prototipos dejan bastante claro que trabajan con arrays.

Segundo, sizeof solo funciona con el nombre de un array, asi que si quieres saber el numero de elementos de un array en otra funcion, o usas una variable global o pasas el numero de elementos como segundo argumento:
int legalMoves(Move ar[], int n);
int legalMoves(Move * ar, int n);

int legalMoves(Move ar[2]; // si el tamaño es fijo, no necesitas pasar el n.elementos ni una variable global

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, si te ha ayudado cuento con tu voto positivo.

Comment: Me parece estupendo que edites los cambios si chocan con tu intención original... pero se pretende que la respuesta sea legible y para eso existen los estilos en StackOverflow

Comment: Vale lo tendre en cuenta. Mira, el problema es que estoy con el movil y es un lio de narices y no sale nada de formato.Si es que aun asi he decidido contestarle ha sido para aligerar la ayuda entre que vuelvo al ordenador y no. Y ya cuando pueda, editar y dejarlo algo mas presentable. Un saludo eferion.

Comment: Ok, no te preocupes.... solo te he informado porque he visto que has deshecho todos los cambios que había hecho. Se lo que es responder desde el movil y es un poco caótico. Prueba a descargarte la aplicación de StackOverflow... mejora un poco la cosa aunque pierdes ciertas funcionalidades respescto a la versión web

Comment: No sabia ni que habia una aplicacion jaja, vale compañero. Gracias por el tip